# WMF file format in XSLFO

Tags: apache, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop, wmf

I am trying to convert Docx to Pdf with the document.xml file from the docx using Apache FOP.

I am facing problem to embed the wmf equation files in PDF, it showing the following error:

WARNING: Glyph "?" (0x2264, lessequal) not available in font "Times-Roman".
Apr 03, 2013 12:29:01 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent

In the PDF the equations are appearing as junck.

Is there any other way to embed WMF file correctly wihtout font issues? Also, please suggest is there any other method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A "WMF" file is not natively supported inside PDF. Whatever process you are using to process the original document must be changed to modify the format of WMF to another supported type for whatever XSL FO processor you are using. In the case of Apache FOP, the support for WMF is only provided though use of Batik.

See [Apache FOP supported image formats](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/graphics.html)